# How to read a text file with multiple paragraphs from assets folder?

Tags: java, android

I have a text file with multiple paragraphs in the assets folder. I want to read it and want to store each paragraph in a String array? How i can do that.

Comment: Are you want to store different paragraph on different String ?

Comment: why you don't just add these paragraphs inside a `<string-array>`

Comment: Yes each paragraph as a string object, how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

How to read from asset file:
[read file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

How to parse a string into paragraphs:
[What character can be used to parse for paragraphs with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188265/what-character-can-be-used-to-parse-for-paragraphs-with-java)